# Prevent to close dialog show automatically in the onBackPressed method

Tags: android, dialog, onbackpressed

I Wan to Show a dialog to the user if click on back button.
I Used this create the `onBackPressed` method like this:

```
 @Override
  public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    if (isNew || !isReport) {

      if (!edtReportContent.getText().toString().isEmpty() && !edtReportContent.getText().toString().equals("")) {

        Toast.makeText(activity, "گزارش شما به عنوان پیش نویس ذخیره شد!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        saveReport(1);

      } else {

        Toast.makeText(activity, "متن گزارش نمی تواند خالی باشد!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_remove_draft);

        Button btnDelete = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View view) {

            discardReport();

          }
        });

        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.show();
      }
  }
```

But when I click on the back button my dialog will show for a few seconds and disappear automatically! What is the problem?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: try rearranging dialog.setCancelable(false); and then dialog.show();

Comment: I did it. But it doesn't help

Comment: remove super.onBackPressed(); and call inside onclick dialog.

Comment: Remove super.onBackPressed();

Comment: Add super.onBackPressed(); in else part of if (isNew || !isReport) {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comment or remove this line of code and try

```
super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: Upvoted, however, try to use the comment section instead for small and 1 line answers. thanks.

Comment: @Tauqir there is nothing wrong with giving "1 line answers" if it helps OP to solve his issue.

Comment: Please don't mind to mark it as correct answer if answer is helpfull

Comment: @H.Brooks, I have just given suggestion. Did not mean to discourage any 1 to write the answers. An answer is an answer. Even if one line is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `super.onBackPressed();`. Your code will now look like this:

```html
  @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            return;
        }

        if(Close_Dialog==null) {
            Close_Dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close ?")
                    .setPositiveButton("close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();
                            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.right_in, R.anim.right_out);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
        }

        if(Close_Dialog !=null)
        {
            if(!Close_Dialog.isShowing())
                Close_Dialog.show();
            else
                Close_Dialog.dismiss();
        }


    }
```